# Chrome ignores delayed HTTP response

Tags: google-chrome, http, post, connection-timeout

There is a web page that after sending a POST request many database transactions take place lasting a significant amount of time.
When clicking to post data, a spinning wheel appears with JS.
Users (of Chrome) complain that the response does not appear and that the whell keeps spinning forever.
I would expect that a connection timeout occurs after 300secs, but wouldn't this generate an error code view in Chrome instead of just keeping the previous view?
Additionally, in case this is indeed a connection timeout, is there any way from server side to keep Chrome waiting after 300secs?
Thank you for your time!

Comment: 5 minutes is a long time, but I believe normally clients will keep waiting indefinitely until there's a reply or error. If you are seeing it stops after 300s, it's likely already something on your server that is set to disconnect after this time. However, I've even seen (bad) routers that disconnect too early so you might not have 100% control. It's probably best to not wait that long and do the work in the background server-side.

Comment: @Evert You are right about the 5mins. It was my faulty assumption based on some QnA mentioning the line 29 here: https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/master:net/socket/client_socket_pool.cc;l=29